# Unable to Install Eclipse ADT Plugin on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to install Eclipse plugin for Android Development.

Steps :

"Help" -> "Install New Software" Added "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7" 
And then checked "Google Plugin for Eclipse" to install it.
The Installation moves upto 40% and I get this error everytime.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/core/3.7/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core_3.0.1.v201206290132-rel-r37.jar.
Connection reset

Needed Help to install ADT plugin for Eclipse for Android Developement.

Comment: Can you include a screen short of the error ?

Comment: @rshetty01 Are you behind proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Issue.
For anybody getting this type of errors.

Steps to Solve :

1 : Download the Eclipse ADT Plugin zip file from the website developer.android.com

2 : Extract the zip file.

3 :  Copy the contents of plugins folder into /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins (On Linux and /Applications/eclipse/plugins on Mac )

Contents are :

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.base_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_20.0.0.v201206242043-391819.jar
```

4 : Now restart the eclipse , Go to "Install new Software" Add the link "http://dl-ssl.google.com/eclipse/plugins" Then install it as mentioned on the android developers site.

Comment: You should accept your answer if it fits your own question. Click on the check icon below the voting arrows on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, try to install the ADT after execute Eclipse as administrator